# How to handle ”Enter” and ”Click” in same function - form submitting

Tags: forms, submit, jquery

How do I trigger the same JQuery function when either:

- the form submit button is clicked
- enter is pressed

Comment: use this as stated in the answer below. `.on('submit', function`

Comment: Yes, this is actually the answer Omar.  If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.  It was a bit of a silly question to ask.  Of course I should be just handling a 'submit'.  I've made this mistake before, that a 'click' on a submit button is a separate event, but obviously results in a submit, which is the same thing that happens on pressing 'enter'.  Because I'm currently only handling a click on the submit button, for some reason my mind went over to also needing to handle a click on 'enter', instead of simply handling the submit.

Comment: Ah - sorry, the question was confusing.  Have edited it now.  Fair enough to downvote it.  Really it's a basic question I'm asking, just got in a muddle, however hopefully it'll help someone else who's either new, or like me just not thinking straight!

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use the keycode for this.

var keycheck = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if(keycheck == 13) { // keycode for Enter key
   //Do something
 }
```